# Django admin model field validation

Tags: python, django, web

I am developing a web application using django admin template. In that application I require a model field validation based on another model field input. Lets say an example, If the user provided "yes" as input value in a **file_required** model field, **Browsefile** model field should be considered as mandatory field. If the user provided "no" as input value in a **file_required** model field, **Browsefile** model field should be considered as optional. Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your **Browsefile** field as optional in your model by setting `blank=True` and then make a validation form to check your **file_required** field, and if the user provided "yes" without entering anything in **Browsefile** then you raise a ValidationError "This field is mandatory".

You can test the user inputted values by checking the cleaned_data of your form and then do what you want if the condition you set are not required :

```
class YourModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        file_required = self.cleaned_date['file_required']
        if file_required == "yes" and not self.cleaned_data['Browsefile']:
            raise forms.ValidationError({'Browsefile': "This field is mandatory"})
```

And don't forget to put a `form = YourModelForm` in your admin.py class.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Here I have been using django admin template to display the model, I have not used modelform. please advise

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly, but you can just put the ```YourModelForm``` class I wrote above in your admin.py, and don't forget to import the forms module with ```from django import forms```